# storing and updating has-many relationships laravel

Tags: laravel, has-many

i m about storing datas using haMany Relatiions 
where Cars may have more than picture 
and each picture can have only one car

Car Modem Car.php

```
class Car extends Model
```

{

```
protected $table = 'cars';
public $timestamps = true;

use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $fillable = array('Marque', 'Model', 'sieges', 'climatisation', 'portes', 'transmition', 'price','url','car_id');

public function cars_images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CarsImage::class);
}
```

CarsImage Model

```
class CarsImage extends Model
```

{

```
protected $table = 'cars_images';
public $timestamps = true;

use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $fillable = array('url');

public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
}
```

}

MyController :

```
public function store(Request $request)   {

      $car = new Car;
      $car->Marque = Input::get('Marque');
      $car->Model = Input::get('Model');
      $car->sieges = Input::get('sieges');
      $car->climatisation = Input::get('climatisation');
      $car->portes = Input::get('portes');
      $car->transmition = Input::get('transmition');
      $car->price = Input::get('price');

      $img = new CarsImage;
      $img->url = 'jean Luc Picard';

      DB::transaction(function() use ($car, $img) {
          $car = $car->save();
          Car::find($car->id)->cars_images()->save($img);
      });
      return 'ok';


  }
```

the problem is the car is saved and the url also is saved but with not the car_id

Any help please ?

Comment: Probably, the problem is connected to the DB structure. Could you show your migrations? Or try to provide a valid local_key in the relationship declaration - return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

Comment: `class CreateForeignKeys extends Migration {

 public function up()
 {
  Schema::table('cars_images', function(Blueprint $table) {
   $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars')
      ->onDelete('cascade')
      ->onUpdate('cascade');
  });`

Comment: when i try  

`Car::find(1)->cars_images()->save($img);`

all go correctly

Comment: I've not used DB:transaction with laravel. Does it work if you don't use the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `create` method:

```
$car = Car::create([
          'Marque' => $request->Marque,
          //other fields...
       ]);
$image = $car->cars_images()->create([
           'url' => 'jean Luc Picard'
       ]);
```

and don't forget to use `$fillable` in your models.

Comment: good morning , again car_id passed with NULL 

`protected $fillable = array('url','car_id');`

whene i use tinker all go alright!

Comment: `public function store(Request $request)
  {

     $datas = $request->except('url');
     $img_name = $request->get('url');

     $car = Car::create($datas);

     $img = CarsImage::create(['url'=>$img_name, 'car_id'=> $car->id]);

     return 'saved ya si zebi saved';


  }` this worked for me , but there is no relation here , it is like to make Relation Manualy

Comment: create method not storing multiple rows with hasmany relation.